# Child process exit with code 1 while running python script from nodejs

Tags: python, node.js, child-process

```
const express = require('express')
const {spawn} = require('child_process');
const app = express()
const port = 8000
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
var dataToSend;
const python = spawn('python', ['script.py']);
python.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
console.log('Pipe data from python script ...');
  dataToSend = data.toString();
});
python.on('close', (code) => {
console.log(`child process close all stdio with code ${code}`);
res.send(dataToSend)
});
})
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port 
${port}!`))
```

This is my index.js file and when I try to run a python script from it, it works only for code that is written before import part in python script. When i run python script individually it runs perfect but not from js file. why ?